# Broken Debian Packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I was attempting to upgrade from Debian 9 (Stretch) to Debian 10 (Buster). However, while my `sudo apt full-upgrade` command was running (after changing my sources.list file), my connection to my server ended. When I attempt to try this command again, (or any apt install command) I get this output:

```
> sudo apt full-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 anthy : Depends: libanthyinput0 but it is not installed
 libuim-plugins : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim : Depends: uim-common (= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-anthy : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-fep : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-gtk2.0 : Depends: uim (= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2 is installed
              Depends: uim-gtk2.0-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but it is not installed
              Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but it is not installed
 uim-gtk3 : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-qt : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-qt5 : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-utils : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-xim : Depends: uim (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2 is installed
           Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The error message suggests running `atp --fix-broken install`, however when I try running this I am faced with another error:

```
> sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aspell-de-alt bdf2psf debian-zh-faq-s doc-debian-fr doc-linux-fr-text doc-linux-pl doc-linux-pl-html docbook-xml fortune-zh gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-bluetooth gnome-sushi iputils-arping libavahi-gobject0 libbind9-140 libblas-common
  libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libdns162 libenca0 libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-qt0 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libgcr-3-common libgfortran3 libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-autoar-common
  libgom-1.0-common libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgweather-3-6 libical2 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libjim0.76 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblwres141 libmusicbrainz5-2
  libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libnfs8 libntfs-3g871 libpcre16-3 libperl5.24 libpoppler64 libprotobuf10 libqt4-designer libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script librarian0 libruby2.3 libscim8v5 libsodium18
  libsuitesparseconfig4 libtelepathy-glib0 libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc libxfont1 linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-11-common linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64 manpages-fr manpages-fr-extra
  myspell-bg myspell-ca myspell-en-gb myspell-it myspell-ku myspell-lt myspell-lv myspell-pl myspell-pt-br myspell-pt-pt myspell-sl myspell-th nautilus nautilus-data rarian-compat rename rsync ruby2.3 scim
  scim-chewing scim-gtk-immodule scim-im-agent scim-modules-socket sgml-data tcpd xml-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libanthyinput0 uim uim-anthy uim-data uim-fep uim-gtk2.0-immodule uim-gtk3 uim-gtk3-immodule uim-plugins uim-qt5 uim-qt5-immodule
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libanthy0 libuim-plugins uim-qt uim-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libanthyinput0 uim-data uim-gtk2.0-immodule uim-gtk3-immodule uim-plugins uim-qt5-immodule
The following packages will be upgraded:
  uim uim-anthy uim-fep uim-gtk3 uim-qt5
5 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 4 to remove and 234 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,558 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,196 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of uim-anthy, which would be broken by installation of uim-data ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure uim-anthy (broken by uim-data)
(Reading database ... 219579 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-4+deb10u2_all.deb ...
De-configuring uim-anthy (1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) ...
Error: in load: file "/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm" not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-4+deb10u2_all.deb (--unpack):
 installed uim-anthy package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-4+deb10u2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I may be able to complete a full system restore if I need to, but since everything else on my system seems operable I was hoping there was some other way to fix this error. I supposedly have successfully upgraded to Debian 10 (Buster), as shown by the output of my `lsb_release` command.

```
> lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

EDIT: I have also tried clearing the issue using dpkg, but it also gives me an error.

```
> sudo dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uim-xim:
 uim-xim depends on uim (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2); however:
  Version of uim on system is 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2.
 uim-xim depends on uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2); however:
  Package uim-data is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package uim-xim (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up uim-mozc:amd64 (2.23.2815.102+dfsg-4) ...
Error: in load: file "/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm" not found
dpkg: error processing package uim-mozc:amd64 (--configure):
 installed uim-mozc:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of anthy:
 anthy depends on libanthyinput0; however:
  Package libanthyinput0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package anthy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uim-gtk2.0:
 uim-gtk2.0 depends on uim (= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2); however:
  Version of uim on system is 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2.
 uim-gtk2.0 depends on uim-gtk2.0-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2); however:
  Package uim-gtk2.0-immodule is not installed.
 uim-gtk2.0 depends on uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2); however:
  Package uim-data is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package uim-gtk2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 uim-xim
 uim-mozc:amd64
 anthy
 uim-gtk2.0
```

I also get an error when attempting to remove some of the broken packages such as anthy and libuim-plugins:

```
> sudo apt remove anthy libuim-plugins

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 uim : Depends: uim-common (= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-anthy : Depends: libuim-plugins (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
             Depends: anthy but it is not going to be installed
 uim-fep : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-gtk2.0 : Depends: uim (= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2 is to be installed
              Depends: uim-gtk2.0-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but it is not going to be installed
 uim-gtk3 : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-qt : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-qt5 : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-utils : Depends: libuim-plugins (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installable
 uim-xim : Depends: uim (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2 is to be installed
           Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-4+deb10u2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any ideas on how to fix these broken dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `anthy` , `uim*` and `libuim-plugins` :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt remove anthy libuim-plugins
sudo apt remove uim.
```

then upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt --purge autoremove
```

Reinstall `anthy` and `uim`:

```
sudo apt install anthy uim
```

You dont need to install [`libuim-plugins`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libuim-plugins), it is only available for debian 9.

Update:

Problem solved by removing `anthy` and all related package to `uim` (`uim*`)  from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` then:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: I tried running the first two commands, but they give me more errors and don't appear to work. See my edited question for more info.

Comment: @dguis I have edited my answer, could you try it , please.

Comment: @dguis the `uim` package seems to be buggy due to `libuim-data` bug.

Comment: Yes, that is what it seems like. I tried to copy the uim.postrm file, but it doesn't appear to exist.
`cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/dpkg/info/uim.postrm': No such file or directory`

Comment: @dguis please check my answer (the update) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560280/153195

Comment: After replacing `status` with `status-old` and re-running the `dpkg --configure -a` command, I am still getting the same error as before. Thanks though for continuing to help me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106357/discussion-between-dguis-and-gad3r).